# Does the size of a placeholder image affect performance?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit

At the moment I am downloading images remotely using a UIImageView category. While the image is downloading I use a placeholder image that is stored in an xcassets folder.

Is it worth having multiple placeholder images for different sizes: small, medium, and large? Or is it worth having 1 placeholder image and using it throughout the application?

Does the size of a placeholder image affect performance?

Comment: I don't know much, say for performance, but when you have a big placeholder image, and it becomes small, it no longer is aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @user2277872 if you're setting the contentMode to AspectFill, it would size appropriately, so I haven't seen any issues with aesthetics.

Comment: That's true, I had forgotten about that. If that's the case, it would seem better to use 1 placeholder image and distribute it throughout

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should have @2x and @3x version of the images, as it will mean less work by the CPU to scale up / down the image on different devices.  Also, there is technically work done by the CPU to scale an image up or down.  However, Apple's graphics processor is pretty efficient at scaling images.

So the technical answer is "Yes, it does affect performance", but in reality it is probably not a big enough difference for you to notice.

Now, if you have built a poorly written app that displays hundreds of these placeholders in a UIScrollView instead of some form of a UICollectionView (which only displays what is on screen, or about to be on screen), you will notice that the slight performance difference for all those images adds up to a large performance difference.